# Most efficient, streamlined way to implement SSL certificates for a mixture of subdomains and top level domains

Tags: ssl, https, certificate

In order to provide https-enabled access to several (e.g. around 5) subdomains and several top level domains on different IPs.

What are the concerns and viability of each of the following approaches?

1. a one-use SSL certificate for each subdomain and domain
2. a multi-domain certificate
3. a mixture of wildcard and single domain
4. a mixture of wildcard and multi-domain certificates?

Comment: downvoter - any feedback? does the edit help clarify the question?

Comment: Cross post to http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/119009/ssl-certificates-for-a-mixture-of-subdomains-and-top-level-domains and answered there.

Comment: I think a lets encrypt related answer would also help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One domain per site can be an issue for old browsers (browsers without SNI support): for a better compatibility it's better to have one certificate per ip.

All others solutions are valid. Some points to help you decide:

- the price (can change a lot. Usually a wildcard certificate is around the same price than a 5-10 domains certificate
- with a wildcard it's easier to add a new subdomain
- with a wildcard you can catch user's typos in subdomains names and redirect them without ssl error
- but a wildcard can't be EV (extended validation, aka "give the green bar")
- a wildcard only work for one level: *.example.com is valid for a.example.com but not for a.b.example.com

Comment: For those exploring solutions or trying to get a hold of the whole process I suggest taking a look at dreamhost documentation and letsencrypt, which is an in Beta free, automated, limited-time (thus forcing renewal, hence the automation) certification authority.